# Can we have a triangular unit cell in crystal lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals

I suppose we cannot have a five fold rotation symmetry because pentagonal unit cells wont fill up all space. But I don't see triangular unit cells filling up all space either, though three fold symmetry is allowed. Am I missing something here

Comment: The list of simple Bravais lattices is very short. The closest you get is hexagonal, which can be represented as triangles (in 2D). But that does not prevent there being 3-fold rotational symmetry axes in other lattices.